# How to avoid callback node js mysql query

Tags: javascript, node.js, callback

I need a sequential output from different tables. I am using mysql.query() nested. But as this function is callback function my required output is not sequential order. Please check the code and advise.

```
var queryString = 'SELECT * FROM tbl_product';
var strcontent = ''; 
fs.appendFile('abcd.txt', '<profile>'); 
fs.appendFile('abcd.txt', '<product>'); 
connection.query(queryString, function(err, rows, fields) {
if (err) throw err;
for (var i in rows) {
    fs.appendFile('abcd.txt', '<product_name>'+rows[i].product_name+'</product_name>'); 
    var emp_query = 'SELECT * FROM tbl_employer';
    fs.appendFile('abcd.txt', '<company>'); 
    connection.query(emp_query, function emp_function(emp_err, emp_rows, emp_fields) {
        if (emp_err) throw emp_err;
        for (var e in emp_rows) {
            fs.appendFile('abcd.txt', '<company_name>'+emp_rows[e].company_name+'</company_name>'); 
        }       
    }); 
    fs.appendFile('abcd.txt', '</company>');    
}
});  
fs.appendFile('abcd.txt', '</product>');    
fs.appendFile('abcd.txt', '</profile>');
```

Comment: Take look at using [`async.eachSeries`](https://github.com/caolan/async#eachSeries) to serialize your async iteration.

Comment: Please can you modify my code by the help of async.eachSeries.